# trying to get item count for a model MVC with condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I can get the count of the Task as follows in the index.cshtml page

```
@Model.Tasks.Count
```

But I need to segregate the count of allocated and unallocated tasks depending on the AllocatedTo property is NULL or not NULL.

```
@Model.Tasks.Count(Condition?)
```

How should I write the condition or do I have any other option?

Comment: `@Model.Tasks.Count(t => t.AllocatedTo == null)`

Comment: I tried that it throws the following error: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type

Comment: What is typeof `Tasks`? (show your GET method code) In any case, this logic belongs in your controller, not the view (i.e the calculated value should be added to a view model (or `ViewBag`) property and then accessed in the view.

Comment: Get method is just preparing the view model from Web API and shows it. Yes I can do that in the controller but I was just guessing if this is possible that will be quicker for me.

Comment: You need to show the code for the GET method. The exception you mentioned is typically because your model is `dynamic` (not a generic type). Its exactly the same code whether its in the controller or view so I don't see how _"it's quicker"_, but it is much harder to test and debug if its in the view :)

Comment: @Stephen - In this case I have to change the ViewModel class for which I need  permissions from Architect, this will be a easier way I thought, anyway I will go with that approach. I cant paste the code here, if needed I can send you via mail for your reference . List<Task> tasks = null; API call and return View(TaskViewModel); TaskViewModel contains List<Tasks> and other properties.

Comment: Try `@Model.Tasks.Where(t => t.AllocatedTo == null).Count()` to see if you get the same error message

Comment: Nope that also is not solving the issue. Throwing the following error :Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type

Comment: As I noted before, it almost certainly means `Model.Tasks` is `dynamic`, perhaps as a result of  the query being generated using a dynamic argument. [This article](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/198/cannot-use-a-lambda-expression-as-an-argument-to-a-dynamically-dispatched-operati) might help to explain

Comment: Thanks  @ Stephen Muecke